# Error de variable no definida en MySql al ejecutar una creación de Store procedure en C#

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio, script, stored-procedure

Estoy queriendo poder realizar modificaciones y crear SPs de MySQL desde el código de la aplicación. Con la mayoría de los SPs no tuve problema pero me encontré con esta excepción:

```
MySqlException: Parameter '@NewID' must be defined.
```

El Script que estoy queriendo correr es el siguiente.:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `SP_RECETA_INSUPD`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_RECETA_INSUPD`(IN FEC date, IN PAC_ID varchar(50), IN ID int, IN TXT varchar(3000), IN DUP tinyint, out NID int)
BEGIN
    set @NewID := 0;
    if (ID = 0) then
        Select @NewID := ifnull(MAX(REC_ID),0) FROM RECETA WHERE REC_IND_FEC = FEC AND REC_IND_PAC_ID = PAC_ID;
        set @NewID := @NewID +1;    
    else
        SET @NewID := ID;
    end if;
    
    IF exists(SELECT 1 FROM RECETA WHERE REC_IND_FEC = FEC AND REC_IND_PAC_ID = PAC_ID AND REC_ID = @NewID) THEN
        UPDATE RECETA
        SET REC_TEXT= TXT, 
            REC_DUP = DUP,
            REC_FEC_IMP  = current_timestamp() 
        WHERE REC_IND_FEC = FEC AND REC_IND_PAC_ID = PAC_ID AND REC_ID = @NewID;
    ELSE
        INSERT RECETA (REC_IND_FEC, REC_IND_PAC_ID, REC_ID, REC_TEXT, REC_DUP, REC_FEC_IMP)
        VALUES (FEC, PAC_ID,  @NewID, TXT, DUP, current_timestamp());
    END IF;
    SET NID := @NewID;
END;
```

Cabe destacar que lo puedo ejecutar desde el workbrech sin problema.

Mi código de C# que lo ejecuta es el siguiente

```
rootConnnection.Open();

mySqlTransaction = rootConnnection.BeginTransaction();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = rootConnnection;
command.Transaction = mySqlTransaction;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = script;   
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

mySqlTransaction.Commit();
command.Dispose();

rootConnnection.Close();
```

En la variable script se encuentra el script que puse al principio.

Cabe destacar que no tuve problemas para otros SPs ni para la creación de tablas o inserción de datos, solo con la variable.

Desde ya les agradezco

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Busqué un poco más y encontré la solución. Para que tome la definición de variables por parte del usuario hay que agregar una opción en el String de conexión.

;Allow User Variables=True

Entonces deberia quedar así

```
string connString = Database=basededatos;Data Source=servidor;User Id=root;Password=root123+;Allow User Variables=True
```

GRacias!!!